# Function/formula to return only the first string proceeding the first carriage return

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Is there a function/formula to return only the first string proceeding the first carriage return using Google Sheets?

Example Text:

```
Bob & Mary Smith   
bob@email.com   
555-111-1234
```

Assuming the above text is in cell A1, I would like the formula to return the following to Cell B1   "Bob & Mary Smith"

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this would do it:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.+)\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Traditional way

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10)) - 1)
```

OR

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(13)) - 1)
```

- Use `CHAR(10)` for line feed (`\n`)
- Use `CHAR(13)` for carriage return (`\r\n` )

Comment: that will always give an error. Did you mean `=iferror( left(A1, find(char(10), A1) - 1), A1 )`?

Comment: You are right. Thanks.